Running DinD without exec
Running this command fails:
docker run --privileged --rm docker:dind docker run hello-world

Error message:
docker: error during connect: Head "http://docker:2375/_ping": dial tcp: lookup docker on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host.
However, this succeeds:
docker run --privileged --rm -d --name test docker:dind 
docker exec -it test sh
> docker run hello-world

A few questions:

What is the reason behind this error?
How to fix it? Either directly or by wrapping it into other docker image (whichever works).

Thank you!
